# Entity Reference Autocomplete on 2 fields entity

Tags: nodes, ajax, entities

Now I have a content type `offer` with some fields AND an **entity reference** of the content type `product`. The entity reference is an autocomplete widget.

When you create an `offer`, you type in the **title** of the `product`. But I also have some other fields on my product like `cnk` for example. So now I would like to have the possibility that you can also type in the cnk. So you get a list of possibilities that match the `title` AND the `cnk` field.

How could I do this?

Comment: The ['Entity Reference Autocomplete'][1] module lets you autocomplete from bundles... 


  [1]: https://www.drupal.org/project/entityreference_autocomplete

Comment: That's not what the bundles mean in that module. You can bundle multiple content types of node, not multiple fields of one content type.